# Backbone collection return wrong length

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm new to Backbone. here is my model:

```
window.Image = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    id: "",
    url: ""
  }
});

window.ImageCollection = Backbone.Model.extend({
  model: Image
});

window.TargetDemoGraphic = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    targetDemographicId: "",
    targetDemographicDescription: "",
    checked: false
  }
});

window.TargetDemoGraphicCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: TargetDemoGraphic,
  url: ServiceUrl + "/targetDemoGraphic/getAll"
});

window.Promotion = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return ServiceUrl + "/promotion/get/" + encodeURIComponent(this.id);
  },
  defaults: {
    id: "",
    item: Item,
    start: "",
    end: "",
    title: "",
    newPrice: "",
    shortContent: "",
    detailContent: "",
    minLoyaltyPoint: "",
    membershipRequired: "",
    loyaltyPointRequired: "",
    loyaltyPointExchangeRequired: "",
    displayOnBanner: "",
    images: ImageCollection,
    bannerImage: Image,
    targetDemoGraphics: TargetDemoGraphicCollection
  }
}

window.PromotionCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Promotion,
  url: ServiceUrl + "/promotion/getAll" 
});
```

My problem is when printing out the nested collection targetDemoGraphics in the template, the length of the collection is always 0.
I'm so confused because the nested collection images work well, it returns correct value.

My backbone view:

```
window.PromotionReview = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize : function(options) {
    _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender');
    var _this = this;
    this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render) {
        _this.beforeRender();
        render();
        _this.afterRender();
        return _this;
    });
    this.render();
},

beforeRender : function() {
},

render : function() {
    var promotion = this.model.toJSON(); 
            //promotion.targetDemoGraphics.length returns = 4           
            //promotion.images.length = 4

            $(this.el).html(this.template(promotion));

    return this;
}
```

});

And the template:

```
<% if (targetDemoGraphics != null && targetDemoGraphics.length > 0) { %>
                            <% for (var idx in targetDemoGraphics) { %>
                                    <p><%= targetDemoGraphics[i].label %></p>
                            <% } %>
                        <% } %>
```

//targetDemoGraphics.length = 0???

...

```
<% if (images != null && images.length > 0) { %>
                            <% for (var idx in images) { %>
                                    <a href="<%=ServiceUrl + '/images/' + images[idx].url %>" data-gallery>
                                        <img style="min-height:100px;height:100px;min-width:100px;width:100px;" src="<%=ServiceUrl + '/images/' + images[idx].url %>">
                                    </a>
                            <% } %>
                        <% } %>
```

//images.length = 4, correct value ???

When printing out the promotion, I got 2 targetDemoGraphics, one contains 4 objects, other one is a function???

Comment: When you do `console.log(promotion)`, what are you getting?

Comment: Some thing strange here, i got 2 instances of targetDemoGraphics:
    + 1: contains 4 objects
    + 2: functions named targetDemoGraphics????

Comment: I don't know why but when I rename targetDemoGraphics to targets, everything works fine.
When printing out promotion, there is only one "targets", which contains 4 objects

Answer (score 0):

If you are nesting collections you better try and use some Backbone extension. Check [Backbone Associations](http://dhruvaray.github.io/backbone-associations/). Using some extension would help you in binding events on the nested `Models` and `Collections` as well and definitely other advantages.